# uint8_t работает также как int8_t

Tags: c++

Недавно начал изучать C++. Написал простенький скрипт, дабы проверить свои знания, в итоге вместо ожидаемого 255, консоль выводит -1(тоже самое, если бы я использовал знаковую разметку int8_t).

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint8_t x = 0;
    std::cout << ~x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вы присвойте `x = ~x` , а потом выводите

Comment: откуда соображение, что ~0 == 255 ?

Comment: Все дело в том, что типом результата `~x` будет `int`, поэтому `cout` и выводит -1

Comment: В С++ отсутствуют встроенные арифметические и битовые операторы для работы с целочисленными типами меньше int, вместо этого они всегда неявно преобразуются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы выполнить `~x`, надо сделать integer promotion, т.е. неявное приведение более мелкого типа до `int` (то же самое для `int16_t` или `uint16_t`, если `int` 32-битный) т.е. получаем `~0x00000000`, что равносильно `(int) 0xFFFFFFFF`, что означает `-1`.